# inject child Angular app into parent app directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a parent Angular app called ng-app="appA", and a directive within it. I have a self-contained Angular app called ng-app="appB". How can I inject appB into the directive within appA?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make appB a dependency of appA like so:

```
angular
    .module('appA', ['appB'])
     //NEED TO INJECT CHILD ANGULAR APP MODULE HERE
    .directive('myDirective',['$rootScope', 'example' function ($rootScope, example) {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {},
            transclude: true,
            templateUrl: '/html/directives/myDirective.html',
            link: function(scope, elem, attr){
                ...
            }
```

Then you just need the code for appB loaded in your app and you are good to go

**EDIT**

I'm not 100% about the structure of your project but look at how this example app is structured

```
angular.module('myApp', [
  'myApp.filters',
  'myApp.services',
  'myApp.directives',
  'myApp.controllers'
])
```

The parent app is `myApp` and it's bootstrapped using `ng-app="myApp"` in the index.html file. Each dependency is created like so:

```
angular.module('myApp.directives', []).
directive('testDirective', [function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      field: '@',
    },
    transclude: true,
    template: "<div ng-transclude></div>",
    link: function(scope, elem, attr, ctrl) {
        console.log(scope);
    }

  }


}]);
```

So long as the myApp.directives js is loaded before the app is bootstrapped, I can use my directive just like this

```
<test-directive>testing</test-directive>
```

Here is a plunk

http://plnkr.co/edit/zzvUR9WBBlqM8QqK6M8K?p=preview

Comment: Hmm I am doing that but getting error. See code above

Comment: How are you bootstrapping your app? Based on your example code you're probably bootstrapping the main app without having the dependencies properly loaded. Are you using `ng-app` or manual bootstrapping?

Comment: For some reason it's complaining now about a controller in an included partial file

Comment: Here is a plunk using your code for an example.
http://plnkr.co/edit/QRW85zMZ9HQHBkzzyu6U?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

when you declare your parent module you need to do it like this

```
angular.module("appA",["appB"]);
```

and you also need to add reference to the file containing the appB module in the html page like this

```
<script src="appB.js"></script>
<script src="appA.js"></script>
```

Be sure that appB is loaded before appA